# Perl client to JAX-WS java server issue

Tags: java, perl, soap, jax-ws, soaplite

I have a JAX-WS java server which publishes a web-service

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="calculator.operation.Calculator")
public class CalculatorWs implements Calculator{

public String[] add(String a) {

    System.out.println(a);

    String[] test = {"this", "that"};
    System.out.println(test);
    return test;
}

}
```

and

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface Calculator {
    String[] add(String a);
}
```

and have a perl client

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'all';
$SOAP::Constants::PREFIX_ENV = 'soapenv';
$SOAP::Constants::PREFIX_ENC = "SOAP-ENC";
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
->service('http://localhost:8080/tomcat/calculator?wsdl')
->soapversion('1.1');
my $var = {'a' => "test"};
my $result = $soap -> add($var);
```

The problem I'm having is that the Java server does not receive the arguments passed by the Perl client, although the value returned by the Java server is received and recognized by the client.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2
007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/
policy" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="ht
tp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://operation.calculator/
" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soapenv:Body><tns:add><c-gensym3
><a xsi:type="xsd:string">test</a></c-gensym3></tns:add></soapenv:Body></soapenv
:Envelope>
```

this is the SOAP request sent by the Perl client. Im assuming the way its building the SOAP request is to blame . But if anyone could help me figure it out, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

(edit)
Here is the WSDL generated by JAX-WS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <!--  Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.3-b01-. 
--> 
- <!--  Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.3-b01-. 
  --> 
- <definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-    wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"    xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"  xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://operation.calculator/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://operation.calculator/" name="CalculatorWsService">
- <types>
- <xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://operation.calculator/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/tomcat/calculator?xsd=1" /> 
</xsd:schema>
</types>
- <message name="add">
 <part name="parameters" element="tns:add" /> 
</message>
- <message name="addResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:addResponse" /> 
</message>
- <portType name="Calculator">
- <operation name="add">
<input wsam:Action="http://operation.calculator/Calculator/addRequest" message="tns:add" /> 
<output wsam:Action="http://operation.calculator/Calculator/addResponse" message="tns:addResponse" /> 
</operation>
</portType>
- <binding name="CalculatorWsPortBinding" type="tns:Calculator">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" /> 
- <operation name="add">
<soap:operation soapAction="" /> 
- <input>
<soap:body use="literal" /> 
</input>
- <output>
<soap:body use="literal" /> 
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
- <service name="CalculatorWsService">
- <port name="CalculatorWsPort" binding="tns:CalculatorWsPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/tomcat/calculator" /> 
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing the java function is great for java programmers, you need to show the WSDL or sample SOAP (read XML) invocation  ... my guess, all you need

```
my $result = $soap -> add( 'test');
```

You should know SOAP::Simple is better at wsdl than SOAP::Lite

Comment: Hey, I did try that, still couldn't get anything. I have added the WSDL generated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I made it work with the following two changes:

1. Name your arguments as in the XSD (`http://localhost:8080/tomcat/calculator?xsd=1`)
2. Don't use the default namespace, but a namespace prefix for the SOAP method (`ns()` method).

Example code:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite                                             
  -> proxy('http://localhost:8080/tomcat/calculator')
  -> ns   ('http://operation.calculator/');

my $response = $soap->call('add', SOAP::Data->name( arg0 => 'Peter Pan'));
```